# Samba Server Make Multiple User Permissions Profiles

Tags: debian, permissions, user-accounts, samba, file-server

I have a Samba file server running, and I was wondering how I could make multiple user accounts that have different permissions. For example, at the moment I have a user, smbusr, but when I ssh to the share, I can read, write, execute, and even navigate out of the samba directory and do stuff on the actual computer. This is bad because I want to be able to give out my IP so friends/family can use the server, but I don't want them to be able to do just anything.

I want to lock the user in the samba share directory(and all the sub directories). Eventually I would like several profiles such as (smbusr_R, smbusr_RW, smbguest_R, smbguest_RW).

I also have a second question related to this, is SSH the best method to connect from other unix machines? What about VPN? Or simply mounting like this:

```
mount -t ext3 -o user=username //ipaddr/share /mnt/mountpoint
```

Is that mounting command above the same thing as a vpn? This is really confusing me.

Thanks for the help guys, let me know if you need to see any files, or need anymore information.

EDIT: Here is my samba share definition:

```
[SAMBA]
path = /samba
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
read list = smbusr_RO
write list = smbusr
```

EDIT2: Here is my entire smb.conf file:

http://pastebin.com/cUGEF3yi

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, Samba can support ACLs nowadays. it takes a few lines in the globals section, and a list of allowed and denied ACLs per share. some adjustment may be needed to your underlying filesystem permissions to support them though, since ext filesystems don't do ACLs by default.

heres a tutorial: http://aisalen.wordpress.com/2007/08/10/acls-on-samba/

and a general reference for the SMB.conf file: http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/manpages-3/smb.conf.5.html

Edit:
try changing your share configuration like this. note that OS groups require an '@' in front, and that write list does not imply read priv, so put both groups in the read list.

add these to globals:

```
invalid users = root
valid users = @smbusers, @smbusers_RO
create mask = 02775
directory mask = 02770

[SAMBA]
comment = Debian File Server With Read Write
invalid users=nobody,nobody
valid users=@smbusr,@smbusr_RO
path = /samba
browseable = yes
guest ok = no
read list = @smbusr,@smbusr_RO
write list = @smbusr
writeable=yes
```

also run 'sudo testparm -s' to check your config file integrity.

in terms of filesystem permissions, you can chown -R your files to be owned by 'root:smbusers', so that your group permission controls who can write, and your other permission can control who can read (smb will make sure that read permissions are only granted to 'smbusers_RO'). then I recommend using SetGID so that all new folders created in the share are owned by :smbusers and all your smbusers will have access to them.

```
chown -R root:smbusers /samba 
chmod -R 2775 /samba
```

Comment: I changed it so now there are only two accounts, smbusr and smbusr_RO. I put my share definition in the main post, does that look alright?


I'm having permissions confusion now. What should I put for my create mask and directory mask if I want nobody besides root to be able to change permissions? Who should I make the owner of my samba share, and what group should I make it? Thanks

Comment: add smbuser to readlist as well. do your filesystem permissions give both groups the appropriate permissions as well?

Comment: I added my smb.conf file to the main post, could you look at it to see if there's anything preventing access?


I'm not quite sure what you mean by my filesystem permissions. I can't seem to even log in as root. Are there things I can try to do in case it is the filesystem permissions?

Comment: see edits above

Comment: What does the preceding 2 in the permissions mean? I'll try to implement this, thanks a lot :)


Also, why do I put the smbusr and smbusr_RO groups rather than the users themselves?

Comment: First off, I've been assuming smbusr is a group. is that not the case? if so you should really consider creating a group, adding whatever users you like to it and then replacing all refs to smbusr above to the group name. sorry for the confusion. the 2 indicates SetGid. when set on a directory, SetGid causes all newly created sub-directories to use the same group owner as the parent. otherwise the default owner is user:user and only that user would be able to access the folder, just all the group members. http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/setgid.html

Comment: I'm totally open to doing a group if it's better. What would be the advantages? Would it be merely that I could have multiple accounts under the same group?

Ah, I get it. Is the group smbusers already made for me? Is it already set up? Would there be any disadvantage by doing:

     chmod -R 2770 /samba

Comment: Also, at the moment write permissions are revoked once I go into a samba subdirectory I can write in samba, but even if I'm logged in as smbusr, I can't write in the sub dirs.

Comment: who is the owner/group on the folder? perhaps using setGID and setting up groups is more of a pain than your needs require. using samba to control your readonly restriction should work. I usually like to lock down the filesystem to match, but its not strictly required for only two users. as for 2770, did you create a group or use smbusers? are both users members? also who is the owner of \samba? the short of it is, to use 2770, both users would have to be either the owner, or in the owner-group. if not, smbuserRO would have to use the 'other' permissions (4 or 5).

Comment: Alright, I have it mostly figured out. I made a group smbusers, and my global settings look just like the ones in your main comment(except I also added my local account(scroty) to the invalid users). My [SAMBA] profile looks just like yours. The only thing I did different at this point is that for chmod I used 02770.

Comment: Here's my current problem(s). I'm able to mount the drive for smbusr, I can read and write in every folder/subfolder just like I intended. However, I can't seem to mount the drive using smbusr_RO. It just pops up another box and asks me to re enter my credentials. My second problem is, when I mount the drive in linux, I can't cd to the mount location without becoming root. Other than that everything works. Could you give me an email or other way to contact you so I can send you the IP address of the server? If you're willing, I'd like you to try to break in and see if I have any weak spots.

Comment: you can reach me temporarily at auto44259584@hushmail.com . please send the output of these commands: 'ls -al /samba', 'members smbusers' (you may have to install 'members'), 'testparm -s', 'groups smbuser', 'groups smbuser_RO'. that should be sufficient to get a good view of the problem.

Comment: I've responded to your email, but if you don't recieve it, check your spam filter. anyway, I'm happy to help at your pace, so let me know once you've run smbpasswd for smbuser_RO, and we'll pick up from there. Cheers.